# Get <p> tag content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-filter

I want to get the content of the `P' tag from the following html code using jQuery.

```
<div id="div_id_disciplina" class="form-group  ">
<label for="id_disciplina" class="control-label  ">
    Disciplina
</label>
<div class="">
    <ul class="token-input-list-facebook">
        <li class="token-input-token-facebook">
            <p>Áudio e Vídeo</p>
            <span class="token-input-delete-token-facebook">×</span>
        </li>
        <li class="token-input-input-token-facebook">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="token-input-id_disciplina">    
        </li>
    </ul>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="id_disciplina" name="disciplina"></textarea>
</div>
```

How to achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18):

Query it with `$('p')` and use the `.text()` function to get the innerHTML as text.

```
$('p').text()
```

Answer (score 8):

`$('p').text()` would get the text inside the paragraph tag.

Comment: If there's gonna be multiple paragraph tags, then you should add a class nameto it and select it that way

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
// If you want to get the html content
$(".token-input-token-facebook p").html();

// Or if you want to get the text
$(".token-input-token-facebook p").text();
```

Comment: it worked! thanks. I added the id_disciplina class too. var p = $("#div_id_disciplina .token-input-token-facebook").find('p');

Answer (score 2):

```
//when document is load
$(function(){
    //get the children of element
    var p = $(".token-input-token-facebook").find('p');
    //and then get the text
    alert(p.text());
})
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/r39qu/

Comment: var p = $("#div_id_disciplina .token-input-token-facebook").find('p');

Answer (score 1):

Just find it and get it's text.

```
var value = $("ul li.token-input-token-facebook > p").text();
```